# QT; QListWidget не хочет очищаться

Tags: c++, qt

Есть функция вызываемая нажатием на кнопку.
В функции есть вызов метода clear() для очистки QListWidget и последующего его наполнения. Проблема в том что при повторном вызове функции программа крашиться, ссылаясь на то что память не может быть очищена. Однако если убрать clear(), то предыдущие элементы в QListWidget останутся.

Comment: Код покажите, так не разобраться

Comment: Оказывается QT слишком самостоятельный. Я хранил массив QListWidgetItem для того чтобы не терять память ,и при каждом входе в функцию очищал его, чтобы потом пересоздать. А метод Clear() очищает память используемых item, в следствии чего и получалось, что при вызове clear() очищать уже было практически нечего (кроме заголовков, но он такой дотошный, ему надо полностью их убивать).